# Why this htaccess is redirecting my subdomains to subdomain folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on    

############################################
## Force web traffic to use HTTPS

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.marclick.com/$1 [R,L]

## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have this `htaccess` file for my server
now my problem is `example.marlick.com` is redirecting to `www.marclick.com/subdomains/example`

my problem is simple but I can't understand what is wrong with my htaccess file

Comment: cant see any rule for subdomains, did you try removing parts and see which lines creates the rewrite?

Comment: yes I removed some rules can you please comment the general rule for not redirecting subdomains to their folders

Comment: there is no logic for creating a rule for not-redirecting, first try to catch the rule that redirect the subdomain, is it possible you have another htaccess or a different vhost?